# ParsleyJS trigger on form fields generated by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, parsley.js

I have a form which, upon a click event does an ajax request to another URL and appends the result (a series of form inputs) to the bottom of my existing form.

The problem I'm having is that Parsley doesn't see these forms in the DOM and thus won't validate them. Is there an `update()` trigger or something that I can apply to Parsley to get it to check and validate the new fields?

I don't have anything special set up - just `$("#form_trigger").parsley();` and all the appropriate form inputs have `class="required"` set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is a current drawback of Parsley 1.x versions, that does not automatically update validation along form updates. That will totally be corrected in next 2.0 release (no current date).

What you could do for now on is to manually tell for Parsley form instance to add new items, that way: `$( '#form' ).parsley( 'addItem', '#itemid' );`

You can see a bit more doc on javascript usage here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html

Hope that helped.

Best

Comment: but it seems like it was not corrected, or am i testing it wrong ?